# Is it a bad idea to call pack() in JFrame.invalidate?

Tags: java, swing

I've built a simple gui that adds panels based on user input. My initial problem was that when the panel was added the frame did not resize. Because it was a jpanel object that handled the user input adding a new panel to itself and therefore could not 'see' the jframe (at least I couldn't find how it could) I couldn't work out how to call `repaint()` or `revalidate()` on the parent frame from within that object. However,through trial and error I did find that this worked

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame(title){
    @Override
    public void invalidate(
         super.invalidate();
         this.pack();
    }
};
```

But because I don't really know what goes on behind the scenes with invalidate I want to know whether this is a good idea or not (It seems kinda sketchy). Any advice would be great, thanks.

EDIT

Hope this makes the problem a bit clearer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class TestFrame {
    JFrame jframe;
    NewPanel jpanel;

    public TestFrame(){
        jframe = new JFrame();  // without above addition frame won't resize
        jpanel = new NewPanel(); 
        jframe.add(jPanel);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){ 
         TestFrame testframe= new TestFrame();
    }
}


class NewPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
     public NewPanel(){
         JTextField textField = new JTextField (10);
         textField.addActionListener(this);
         this.add(textField);
    }

    // Adds a label when action is performed on textfield
    @Overide
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        JPanel extraPanel = new JPanel();
        extraPanel.add(new JLabel("hi"));
        this.add(extraPanel);
        this.revalidate(); this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve]. We need more context on how you built your application and thus provide better answers and possible different approaches and will explain better your question, right now it's a little bit difficult to understand what your app does

Comment: Added a stripped out example to show what im trying to do. Hope thats a bit clearer

Comment: Can you explain what a `JTextFrame` is? It's the first time I see it, is it a `JTextArea`? A `JTextField`? Also, can you include the `imports`? I don't have an IDE for Java at my work, so I have to compile from terminal.

Comment: _JTextFrame_ Are you referring to `com.ibm.richtext.swingui.JTextFrame` ?

Comment: No sorry i did mean TextField. Doing this on my phone 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not that `revalidate()` or `repaint()` aren't working.

The issue here is that your `JFrame` has been `pack()`ed already and thus it has a preferred size set. If you want to change its size you need to call `pack()` on it again. Not necessarily to call it on `invalidate()`.

I made some changes to your code to compile (typos) and I came with this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrame {
    JFrame jframe;
    NewPanel jpanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestFrame());
    }

    public TestFrame(){
        jframe = new JFrame();  // without above addition frame won't resize
        jpanel = new NewPanel(); 
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    class NewPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        public NewPanel(){
            JTextField textField = new JTextField (10);
            textField.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(textField);
        }

        // Adds a label when action is performed on textfield
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            System.out.println("WOLOLO");
            JPanel extraPanel = new JPanel();
            extraPanel.add(new JLabel("hi"));
            this.add(extraPanel);
            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();
            jframe.pack();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to solve this is to override `getPreferredSize` method from the `JPanel`:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
}
```

And you can delete `jframe.pack()` in the previous code.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Am I right in saying this works because the NewPanel is now an inner class? Also sorry about the typos

Comment: I made that change as an inner class just to compile a single file, as I said, I'm not using an IDE so for me make it an inner class was easier. But this works as long as they are in the same file. If you want them to be separate then we'd have to do something else (a different approach)